# Get the Parent key and the nested value in nested json

Tags: python, json, nested

I have a nested json for a JSON schema like this:

```
{
  "config": {
    "x-permission": true
  },
  "deposit_schema": {
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "control_number": {
        "type": "string",
        "x-cap-permission": {
          "users": [
            "test@test.com"
          ]
        }
      },
      "initial": {
        "properties": {
          "status": {
            "x-permission": {
              "users": [
                "test3@test.com"
              ]
            },
            "title": "Status",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "main_status": {
                "type": "string",
                "title": "Stage"
              }
            }
          },
          "gitlab_repo": {
            "description": "Add your repository",
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "directory": {
                  "title": "Subdirectory",
                  "type": "string",
                  "x-permission": {
                    "users": [
                      "test1@test.com",
                      "test2@test.com"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "gitlab": {
                  "title": "Gitlab",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "type": "object"
            },
            "title": "Gitlab Repository",
            "type": "array"
          },
        "title": "Initial Input",
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "title": "Test Analysis"
  }
}
```

The JSON is nested and I want to have the dict of `x-permission` fields with their parent_key like this:

```
{
 "control_number": {"users": ["test@test.com"]},
 "initial.properties.status": {"users": ["test3@test.com"]},
 "initial.properties.gitlab_repo.items.properties.directory": {"users": [
                      "test1@test.com",
                      "test2@test.com"
                    ]}
}
```

I am trying to do implement recursive logic for every key in JSON like this:

```
def extract(obj, parent_key):
    """Recursively search for values of key in JSON tree."""
    for k, v in obj.items():
        key = parent_key + '.' + k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if v.get('x-permission'):

                return key, v.get('x-permission')
            elif v.get('properties'):
                return extract(v.get('properties'), key)
    return None, None


def collect_permission_info(object_):
    # _schema = _schema.deposit_schema.get('properties')
    _schema = object_ # above json
    x_cap_fields = {}

    for k in _schema:
        parent_key, permission_info = extract(_schema.get(k), k)
        if parent_key and permission_info:
            x_cap_fields.update({parent_key: permission_info})
    return x_cap_fields
```

I am getting empty dict now, what I am missing here?

Comment: Your schema is not valid JSON.

Comment: Oops, Got edited. Now its showing correct.

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does wrong?

Comment: It does not read the `status` dict where the `x-permission` is

Comment: Where *should* it do that, and why isn't it?

Comment: Why `"experiment"` and not `"_experiment"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the comments and the answers. I got this solution working for my use case.

```
def parse_schema_permission_info(schema):
    x_fields = {}

    def extract_permission_field(field, parent_field):
        for field, value in field.items():
            if field == 'x-permission':
                x_fields.update({parent_field: value})
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                key = parent_field + '.' + field
                if value.get('x-permission'):
                    x_fields.update(
                        {key: value.get('x-permission')}
                    )
                extract_permission_field(value, key)

    for field in schema:
        extract_permission_field(schema.get(field), field)

    return x_fields
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this generator of key/value tuples:

```
def collect_permission_info(schema):
    for key, child in schema.items():
        if isinstance(child, dict):
            if "x-permission" in child:
                yield key, child["x-permission"]
            if "properties" in child:
                for rest, value in collect_permission_info(child["properties"]):
                    yield key + "." + rest, value
```

Then call it like this:

```
result = dict(collect_permission_info(schema))
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues I can spot:

1. You use the `parent_key` directly in the recursive function. In a case when multiple properties exist in an object (`"_experiment"` has 2 properties), the path will be incorrect (e.g. `_experiment.type.x-permission` is constructed in second loop call). Use a new variable so that each subsequent for loop call uses the initial `parent_key` value
2. The `elif` branch is never executed as the first branch has priority. It is a duplicate.
3. The return value from the recursive `execute(...)` call is ignored. Anything you might find on deeper levels is therefore ignored
4. Judging by your example json schema and the desired result, a recursive call on the `"initial": {...}` object should return multiple results. You would have to modify the `extract(...)` function to allow for multiple results instead of a single one
5. You only check if an object contains a `x-permission` or a `properties` attribute. This ignores the desired result in the  provided `"initial"` schema branch which contains `x-permission` nested inside a `status` and `main_status` branch. The easiest solution is to invoke a recursive call every time `isinstance(v, dict) == true`